# How to choose arm64 based graviton2 for aws lambda in serverless configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to configure an AWS Lambda function to run on arm64 based AWS Graviton2 processor in the serverless configuration.

[image: AWS Lambda Configuration]

Comment: Have you tried to check the "arm64" option in your picture? What happened?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-functions-powered-by-aws-graviton2-processor-run-your-functions-on-arm-and-get-up-to-34-better-price-performance/

Comment: Its too new. There is no option for that in cloudformation for now.

Answer (score 5):

I found the way in [Serverless AWS Functions Documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#:%7E:text=login/%23credentials-store-,Instruction%20set%20architecture,-By%20default%2C%20Lambda).
By default lambda functions run on 64-bit x86 architecture CPUs. To switch all the functions to AWS Graviton2 processor:

```
provider:
...
  architecture: arm64
```

To switch only one function, set it in the functions context:

```
functions:
  hello
    ...
    architecture: arm64
```